# take function from java and Writing same function in php but don't work

Tags: java, php, encoding

in Java I have the following function:

```
public static String Signature(String keyString) {
    try {
        SecretKey secretKey = null;

        byte[] keyBytes = keyString.getBytes();
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");

        mac.init(secretKey);

        Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;

        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateformat,locale);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String baseString = sdf.format(d);

        date = baseString;

        byte[] text = baseString.getBytes();

        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(mac.doFinal(text))).trim();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { return null; }
}
```

I'm trying to create a function in PHP that will give the same result for the same "data" and "secret" parameters.

I tried to use this code:

```
$key = "ooh";
$date = '2020-01-13 04:02:01'; 
$gmt_date = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date) );
$signature= base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', base64_encode($gmt_date), $key,true));
echo $signature;
```

But I get different results for the same input

Comment: these do tasks in different order( in Java the HASH_HMAC is early on but n PHP is last ), the dates are possibly different format etc so no wonder you get different results

Comment: In your PHP code you base64_encode the `$gmt_date`, while in your Java code you don't do the same with `text`